# Android image animation using multiple images

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am looking for an animation liberary of code which will help me to do 360 degree animation using set of images (Around 60 images for horizontal rotation). Also images are in SDCARD and not in application.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom view and override onDraw(Canvas) method and draw the bitmap of desired image.

You can keep track on the current "direction" in degree and calculate which should be displayed in what location using Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap,Matrix,Paint).

Here's an example of moving one image according to phone orientation.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class SkySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements OnTouchListener {

    private static final String TAG = SkySurfaceView.class.getSimpleName();
    private double viewPortX, viewPortY;
    private int starX, starY;
    private Bitmap target;
    private int targetWidth, targetHeight;
    private int vpWidth, vpHeight;
    private Matrix skyMatrix, skyMatrix2;
    private Matrix skyMatrix3;
    private Bitmap star;
    private Paint paint;
    private Rect touchRect, touchRect2, touchRect3;

    public SkySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
        viewPortX = viewPortY = 0;
        skyMatrix = new Matrix();
        skyMatrix2 = new Matrix();
        skyMatrix3 = new Matrix();

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        paint.setDither(true);

        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        Options opt = new Options();
        opt.inSampleSize = 2;
        opt.inScaled = false;
        opt.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
        star = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.star,
                                            opt);
        touchRect = new Rect(0, 0, star.getWidth(), star.getHeight());
        touchRect2 = new Rect(0, 0, star.getWidth(), star.getHeight());
        touchRect3 = new Rect(0, 0, star.getWidth(), star.getHeight());

        this.setWillNotDraw(true);
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);
    }

    public void setTarget(Bitmap b) {
        target = b;

        targetHeight = target.getHeight();
        targetWidth = target.getWidth();
    }

    public void init() {

        this.starX = (int) (vpWidth * Math.random()) + vpWidth;
        this.starY = (int) ((vpHeight - star.getHeight()) * Math.random());
        Log.i(TAG, "drawn star on " + starX + "," + starY);
        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        Log.i(TAG,
              "target dimension is " + target.getWidth() + "x"
              + target.getHeight());
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(target.getWidth(),
                                            target.getHeight(), Config.RGB_565);
        c.setBitmap(bitmap);
        c.drawBitmap(target, 0, 0, paint);
        c.drawBitmap(star, starX, starY, paint);
        c.drawBitmap(star, starX - targetWidth, starY, paint);
        target.recycle();
        setTarget(bitmap);
        setWillNotDraw(false);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        super.performClick();
        return false;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param x
     *            - [-1:1]
     * @param y
     *            - [-1:1]
     */
    public void setViewPort(double x, double y) {

        viewPortX = x;
        viewPortY = y;

        int tempX = (int) (targetWidth * (viewPortX));
        int tempY = (int) (targetHeight * (viewPortY - 1));

        tempY = Math.max(tempY, -(targetHeight - vpHeight) / 2);
        tempY = Math.min(tempY, +(targetHeight - vpHeight / 2));

        Log.i(TAG,
              String.format("%d %d , %d %d, %d %d", tempX, tempY, tempX
                            - targetWidth, tempY, tempX + targetWidth, tempY));

        skyMatrix.reset();
        skyMatrix.postTranslate(tempX, tempY);
        skyMatrix2.reset();
        skyMatrix2.postTranslate(tempX - targetWidth, tempY);
        skyMatrix3.reset();
        skyMatrix3.postTranslate(tempX + targetWidth, tempY);

        int xx = (tempX + starX);
        while (xx < targetWidth) {
            xx += targetWidth;
        }
        touchRect.offsetTo(xx % targetWidth, (tempY + starY) % targetHeight);
        touchRect2.offsetTo(xx % targetWidth - targetWidth, (tempY + starY)
                            % targetHeight);
        touchRect3.offsetTo(xx % targetWidth + targetWidth, (tempY + starY)
                            % targetHeight);
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public void setViewportSize(int x, int y) {
        vpWidth = x;
        vpHeight = y;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        super.onDraw(c);
        c.drawBitmap(target, skyMatrix, paint);
        c.drawBitmap(target, skyMatrix2, paint);
        c.drawBitmap(target, skyMatrix3, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float ex = event.getX();
        float ey = event.getY();

        Log.i(TAG, "touched " + ex + " " + ey);
        if (touchRect.contains((int) ex, (int) ey)) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onCaptured();
            }
        } else if (touchRect2.contains((int) ex, (int) ey)) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onCaptured();
            }
        } else if (touchRect3.contains((int) ex, (int) ey)) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onCaptured();
            }
        }

        return false;
    }


    public void setListener(OnStarCaptureListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

}
```

In this example, "target" is a sky image. Whenever setViewPort is called, (x and y [-1:1]), the image's drawing matrix is updated and "invalidate()" is called. The onDraw() method call will draw the "target" with offset.